# npm + Mocha --watch (not accurately watching files)

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, npm, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha with npm, and doing an "npm test" to start up mocha.  It has the --watch enabled in the mocha.opts, but for some reason it's not accurately watching.  When I make a change to my test file, and then save it, whether I put in a faulty test or an ok test, I get the same thing:  0 passing (in green), whereas, when I first run mocha, I get 2 passing.

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: are you putting your tests in a "describe" and an "it"? If you haven't you will pass all tests but 0 will be displayed

Comment: it appears this [may be a bug](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/2327) in windows environments

Answer (score 27):

You need to ensure that npm passes the CLI opts through to mocha using:

`npm test -- --watch`

This will pass the watch flag when npm runs mocha.

Answer (score -2):

I am able to get this to work.  I wonder if the problem is that your `mocha.opts` needs to be in the `test` subdirectory?

In any case, a working proof of concept is on `npm` as `smikes-mocha-watch-example`, and you can test this via

```
mkdir test
npm install smikes-mocha-watch-example
cd node_modules/smikes-mocha-watch-example
npm install
npm test
```

I will suggest that you probably don't want `npm test` to run `mocha --watch` since `npm test` is sometimes run programmatically, and it would look like an indefinite hang if it ran with `--watch`.  A better solution might be to use `mocha` as the `test` script and `mocha --watch` as a new script, e.g., "watch":

```
$ cat package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "watch": "mocha --watch"
   }
}
$ npm test
... runs mocha
$ npm run watch
... runs mocha --watch
```

Comment: I do not like this answer, if question was if mocha.opts needs to be in test subdirectory, this working example is just a working example ...
mocha.opts need to be in the directory where mocha --watch is run, and you can watch things that are not in test subdirectories:

`mocha --watch tests/`

it will watch all subdirectory, but run only tests/* 's subdirectory scripts, but `mocha.opts` need to be in the directory where mocha is ran